# Using two mice to perform completely different actions in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, api

I'm currently trying to develop an application to use two mice to perform completely different actions in Windows. However, after having spent couple days on it, I'm starting to wonder if what I want to do is even possible using Windows APIs. As I'm far from being an expert in Windows APIs, I would like to get your opinions to know whether I'm going in the right direction or whether I should try to do it completely differently (maybe developing a driver ?).

Here's what I want to do : Imagine two mice are plugged in my computer. I would like to use the first one as a regular mouse, while the second one would be used to perform completely different actions. For instance, by clicking the second left mouse button, it would open a new tab in Firefox (sending a CTRL+T command to FireFox app) and when clicking the right button, it would send a CTRL+C. Then, by moving the second mouse upwards, it would zoom in, and when moving it downwards, the firefox page would zoom out (so the mouse cursor on screen would remain fix while doing that !). The idea is to recognize as well which application is currently used (which one has mouse/keyboard focus) and perform different actions depending on it. So for instance, the second mouse left click would generate a CTRL+T in FireFox, a CTRL+B in WORD and a CTRL+S in Notepad (in fact, the idea is to parameterize those actions at will). All of that while the first mouse must continue to act just as a regular mouse.

So, it's important to understand that my application will run in the background and will never, per se, interact directly with the user (no GUI as it doesn't require the user to input anything). Its purpose is just to modify the mouse inputs coming from the second mouse and send other inputs(messages) to the application currently being used.

So far, I'm using raw input. I'm able to differentiate which mouse is being used and I'm able to send messages (application specific) to other applications when an action is performed on the second mouse. I'm even able to lock the cursor on screen when the second mouse is moved (so as only the corresponding message is sent to the application of interest !). However, I'm unable to block the button messages sent by the second mouse to the app with the mouse focus. Hence, when clicking on the second mouse right button in Notepad for instance, my specific command ("aaa" for the moment as I'm just trying with letters for sake of simplicity) is sent (and displayed in the notepad window) BUT the contextual Notepad menu opens as well…  (hence it's received as well a `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message).

My question is then : How can I block the mouse button messages ((`WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, and so on…) to be received by other applications when the second mouse is used? Is it even possible ? The problem is that (in my understanding) those messages have higher priority over the `WM_input messages`… So when I read the `WM_input` message in my application and detects that the button was pressed from the second mouse, it's already too late and the `WM_xBUTTONDOWN` was already sent !)

I know that using the mouse hooks, I could block those but then, there is no way to differentiate the origin of the message (and of course, detecting which mouse is used is the main point of my application).

I've tried as well using DirectInput8 but it doesn't support anymore the usage of several mice (Windows specifically says to use raw input to this effect).

So, I guess that by know you've gotten that I'm quite lost and have no idea whether what I want to do it even achievable. Any help would be more than welcome.

Looking forward to reading your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest hooks, but then I read that you looked into that already. I guess, the last resort for your problem would be to write your own driver.
After Windows installed the second mouse in it's usual way, you can go to the Device Manager and change the driver of the mouse you want to "repurpose" to your own driver.

Although, developing a driver is probably nothing one will do as a side task in a project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was secretly hoping that there would exist a way to do it without having to write a driver but it seems I don't have any other choices than digging into driver-related stuffs. The path to accomplish my goal is going to be a lot more tortuous now ! :)