# Upper filter device driver for a mouse

Tags: c, filter, driver, mouse

I've just started diving into driver related stuffs as what I want to do (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970592/using-two-mice-to-perform-completely-different-actions-in-windows)) seems undoable with a "regular" application. For now, I'm just trying to install a Kernel Mode Driver (KMDF) as an upper filter for the mouse I want to modify the behaviour. The source files are not empty as they are filled in according to the Visual Studio KMDF template. The only modification I did so far in those source files was adding those two lines of code in the CreateDevice routine :

```
WdfFdoInitSetFilter(DeviceInit);

WdfDeviceInitSetDeviceType(DeviceInit, FILE_DEVICE_MOUSE);
```

to specify that the driver is a mouse filter driver.

However, I'm having trouble to install it as I would like on my virtual machine. Here is the INF file (don't pay too much attention to the comments, I just added them to better understand what's going on as it's the first time I'm confronted to such a file):

```
;
; EGMC_filter.inf
;

[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$" ;Operating system for which the INF file is valid
Class=Mouse ; The class is mouse
ClassGuid={4d36e96f-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} ; Mouse class GUID
Provider=%ManufacturerName% ; is specified in the Strings section (bottom of this file)
CatalogFile=EGMC_filter.cat ; for signature
DriverVer= ; TODO: set DriverVer in stampinf property pages


; The DestinationDirs section specifies the target destination directory for all copy, delete and/or rename operations
; on files referenced by name elsewhere in the INF file

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12 ; directory is \Drivers on WinNT platforms
EGMC_filter_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles = 11 ; Directory is  \system32 on WinNt platforms

[SourceDisksNames] 
1 = %DiskName%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles] 
EGMC_filter.sys  = 1,,
WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll=1 ; make sure the number matches with SourceDisksNames

;*****************************************
; Install Section
;*****************************************

[Manufacturer] ; This section is used to list all devices handled by the driver
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$ ;stands for architecture. Is modified depending on x64 or x86

[Standard.NT$ARCH$] ; This is a model section
%EGMC_filter.DeviceDesc%=EGMC_filter_Device, USB\VID_093A&PID_2510; Specifying the Hardware ID for which to install the driver. No revision nb specified

[EGMC_filter_Device.NT] ; This is a DDInstall section
CopyFiles=Drivers_Dir ; CopyFiles directive that specify a copyfiles section (Drivers_Dir)
AddReg=EGMC_filter.AddReg

[EGMC_filter.AddReg]
HKR,,"UpperFilters",0x0010008,"EGMC_filter" ; REG_MULTI_SZ value 

[Drivers_Dir] ; This is a CopyFile section.
EGMC_filter.sys ; All the files in this section are copied to the specified directory in the DestinationDirs section.

;-------------- Service installation



[EGMC_filter_Device.NT.Services]
AddService = EGMC_filter,%SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE%, EGMC_filter_Service_Inst ; create a service installation section




; -------------- EGMC_filter driver install sections
[EGMC_filter_Service_Inst]
DisplayName    = %EGMC_filter.SVCDESC%
ServiceType    = 1               ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType      = 3               ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl   = 1               ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary  = %12%\EGMC_filter.sys ; create a value in the registry with the fully qualified path of the driver's file


;
;--- EGMC_filter_Device Coinstaller installation ------
;

[EGMC_filter_Device.NT.CoInstallers]
AddReg=EGMC_filter_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg ;Add a registry section
CopyFiles=EGMC_filter_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles

[EGMC_filter_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000, "WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

[EGMC_filter_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles]
WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll

[EGMC_filter_Device.NT.Wdf]
KmdfService =  EGMC_filter, EGMC_filter_wdfsect
[EGMC_filter_wdfsect]
KmdfLibraryVersion = $KMDFVERSION$

[Strings]
SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE= 0x00000002
ManufacturerName="EGMC" ; My manufacturer name
ClassName="Mouse" ;  ClassName of the device
DiskName = "EGMC_filter Installation Disk" ; the disk name. DON'T KNOW WHERE IT COMES FROM !!!
EGMC_filter.DeviceDesc = "EGMC Filter Device"
EGMC_filter.SVCDESC = "EGMC_filter Service"
```

I'm trying to install my driver in a virtual machine running Windows 10. The VM is configured to support USB 2.0 and I've added a USB device filter in order for the VM to detect my particular mouse (otherwise, the VM couldn't distinguish the different mice connected).

First I tried deploying it via Visual Studio using the "Install/Reinstall and Verify" option in the project properties (configuration properties -> Driver Install -> Deployment). Note that remove previous driver versions before deployment is selected.

It didn't work and I got the following error messages :

```
[17:32:01:625]: ERROR: Task "Default Driver Package Installation Task" failed to complete successfully. Look at the logs in the driver test group explorer for more details on the failure.
[17:32:02:348]: Driver Post Install Actions
[17:32:02:348]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[17:32:02:375]: Copying required files for "Driver Post Install Actions".
[17:32:02:934]: [Driver Post Install Actions] Command Line:
$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_DriverPostInstall'" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Driver_Post_Install_Actions_00011.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[17:32:05:387]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[17:32:05:388]: Task "Driver Post Install Actions" completed successfully
Driver Deployment Task Failed: Default Driver Package Installation Task
```

It may sound stupid but I was unable to locate the logs in the driver test group explorer to get more info about the error.

Secondly, I tried using the "Hardware ID Driver" option instead of the "Install/Reinstall and Verify" one with the following Hardware ID "USB\VID_093A&PID_2510" (same as the one specified in the INF). It worked this time. However, I'm not sure to understand exactly why. So now that you got a better picture of what I'm doing, here are my questions :

1) I did understand that the SourceDisksNames section is used to specify the name of a disk (CD-rom, DVD) containing the .sys file of the driver. However, I don't understand how to install a driver from such a disk practically. Imagine I buy a specific hardware and it comes with a CD with the corresponding driver files. Once the CD is in the player, what should I do ? Should I run the INF file in order to install it ? From what I remember the only time I had to install a driver from a disk it was a .exe file.

2) What if I want to release my driver package via Internet ? What's the point of this section then ?

3) By default when I created the project, VS filled the disk name with "EGMC_filter Installation Disk". What does it correspond to ? Should I modify it ?

4) I don't understand how the deployment process works. I guess that VS first transfers the driver package (containing the .INF, .cat and .sys) to the VM and then launches the .INF file in the VM. Is that right ? If yes, what does the DiskName correspond to in the VM ? Does VS create some kind of ISO containing the package ? Where can I find where the package is stored in the VM ?

5) Does the deployment process differ when using the "Hardware ID Driver Update" and the "Install/Reinstall […]" options ?

6) Any idea why I can't install my driver using the "Install/Reinstall and Verify" option ? What's wrong with the INF file ? Has it something to do with the Disk name ?

7) Despite having read [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-drivers/develop/deployment_properties_for_driver_projects), I'm confused about why I can deploy my driver with the "Hardware ID" option considering that I didn't respect the form Root\xxx (I saw this page afterwards). However, it seems clear that for what I want to do, I must install my driver using the other option. Any idea why it still seems to work (at least partially) ?

8) After the "incorrect" installation is completed, a "EGMC Filter Device" entry is added to the Device Manager under Mice and other pointer devices even when the mouse of interest is unplugged. Why is this ? When I plug it, another entry appears.

9) When my driver is installed, the mouse doesn't work anymore (it doesn't even light up !). However, as the upper filter doesn't do anything for now, the mouse should work normally. The only explanation I've found so far is that the driver is installed as a function driver and not as a filter one. Could it be the case ? In the registry of the VM, I'm unable to find the UpperFilters keys with the "EGMC_filter" value in the section "Ordinateur\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e96f-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}". The only one I found is : "UpperFilters : VboxMouse mouclass". It comforts me in my idea that the driver is installed as a function one… Could the VM interferes with my driver ?

10) The driver details of the mouse of interest (left) and the regular one (right) also confuse me as the mouhid is missing from the former. [image: Driver details]

11) Lastly, what's the point of specifying in the driver code that it's a filter driver ? What does it change concretely ?

I know it's a long post and that I'm asking quite specific questions but I hope you won't mind and hopefully some experts right there will be able to answer them.

I'm looking forward to your replies.

Guillaume.

Comment: Writing a kernel driver for Windows properly is hard, you may consider taking a class. Try to achieve your goal (modification of mouse behavior?) without a driver. What exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: Yes, I know it's a tough task but I'm very much interested in learning how to do so. Do you have any suggestions of a good class I could take ? I guess you didn't read this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970592/using-two-mice-to-perform-completely-different-actions-in-windows  where I explain rather thourougly what I want to do and the reason why I can't do it without a driver.